# setMinimumScale on WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webView that I manipulate with this code: (this all works fine)

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.stats_webview);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
myWebView.setInitialScale(getScale());
```

Which gets the initial scale from this method

```
private int getScale(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager)
    getSystemService(StatsActivity.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size); 
    int width = size.x;
    Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(720);
    val = val * 100d;
    return val.intValue();
}
```

That all works fine and loads the view slightly scaled down to fit the screen from my 720pixel web source. The problem is that once someone zooms in, they cannot zoom back out all the way to the initial scale. They can only zoom back out to a scale of 1, so they are unable to fit the entire page back on the screen. I've found references to a setMinimumScale method but it doesn't seem to be available any more. Am I just missing an include file or is there a new way to accomplish this?

I have tried:

```
myWebView.setMinimumScale(getScale());
```

and

```
myWebView.getSettings().setMinimumScale(getScale());
```

but neither works.

Comment: is editing the HTML file an option? If yes, you can use the viewport meta tag.

Comment: I can edit it but since the minimum scale will be different I have no way to know what to set it to. Also when I try setting width=device-width in the meta tag it doesn't appear to work and loads much too large.

Comment: Actually I just needed to include "target-densitydpi = device-dpi" to my meta tag. Works great now, thanks a ton! If you put this in an answer instead of comment I'll check it. :)

Comment: this is the final working meta tag 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, target-densitydpi = device-dpi" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If editing the HTML file is an option, you can use the viewport meta tag. 
check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html) for more details.

Comment: Adding `code`(<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, target-densitydpi = device-dpi" />) to the html worked great!